# Dynamic layout in auto layout in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout

I am creating a login screen in iOS using auto-layout & size classes.I have added lot of constraints for making dynamic UI.But the UI does not seem to be dynamic.I have added the views center horizontal constraint to make all view in center.I have given vertical spacing between text view & login button.I have added bottom space for login button & top space for imageview.How can increase the width of views dynamically? I also want to give equal space from top & bottom.[image]

Comment: Set  Leading and trailing constraints for imageview and remove any hieght or witdh constraints if added. However it is difficult to help you if you do not show your constraints here

Comment: I want dynamically incearse the width & height of views.Do i need to create diffrent constraint for diffrent screen sizes ?

Comment: You might need to use size classes for landscape and portrait. Otherwise setting Leading and Trailing constraints along with Top and Bottom constraints for imageview (Without any height or width constraint) should do it.

Comment: For eg.If i set leading space of 10 & trailing of 10 .Then 10 is fix value for all the screens ?

Comment: Yes. if you set 10px than it will adjust width dynamically by layout engine

Comment: Then why not width & height adjusting ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74614/discussion-between-bhumit-and-techguy).

Answer (score 1):

Add appropriate constraints to pin edges i.e leading, trailing, top and bottom edges or appropriate subviews to the superview.

Add these constraints:

1. Pin top edge of Image view to top edge of superview .
2. Similarly pin leading and trailing edge of ImageView to respective edge of superview.
3. Pin leading and trailing edge of both the text field to respective edge of superview.
4. Pin bottom edge of button to bottom edge of superview.

Here is the way you could pin edges:

[image]

Comment: I have to change the height & width of view depending upon screen size.Should i not give width & height of imageview ?

Comment: If you want the subviews to grow as per the screen size it is better to pin the edges to that of superview rather than setting height and width of subviews.

Comment: how to pin edges ? you mean trailing & leading space?

Comment: I added screenshots for explanation.